# Use "%" in sitevision config

Tags: java

I want to configure the width of an element in sitevision, the values can be auto, [n]px and [0-100]%.

Auto and pixel width works like a charm but when using percent the config does not accept the % sign. As if it was escaped. So when i want an element to be 100% wide it does not work.

I do not get an error message and if i make something like

```
String pWidth = request.getParameter(PARAM_WIDTH);
if(pWidth.endsWith("per")){
    pWidth = pWidth.replace("per","%");
}
```

Then it works, problem is when i then open the config, it displays "%" and requires the text to be rewritten to per again before save.

And "per" litteral is not as userfriendly as "%". And the config needs to be overly userfriendly.

**( This should be tagged with sitevision, but there is no such tag, so i will tag it with java, since i need 1500pts to make one )**

Comment: try %25 instead of %

Comment: %25 does not work since there is a % in there. Thought about that though.